# HTML5: detect horizontal swiping and vertical scrolling on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, touch, swipe

I need to detect swipe right and swipe left on mobiles, while also allowing up/down scrolling.

This works on the iPhone, but not the Android. Essentially the choice seems to be either scroll or swipe.

I've tried jquery mobile and http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library.

Here http://wilsonpage.co.uk/touch-events-in-chrome-android/ it is concluded "To achieve the desired result I will now have to use synthetic JavaScript powered scrolling for both horizontal panning and swiping as well as vertical scrolling."

Has anyone come up with another solution or are there any libraries to handle this?

I tried to change the alter the netCU code to change whether e.preventDefault() is called since this seems to be relevant. No luck. Swiping does not work with the below code.

```
   (function($) { 
   $.fn.touchwipe = function(settings) {
     min_move_x = 30;
     min_move_y = 20;
     var config = {
            wipeLeft: function() { },
            wipeRight: function() { }
     };

     if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

     this.each(function() {
         var startX;
         var startY;
         var isMoving = false;

         function cancelTouch() {
             this.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
             startX = null;
             isMoving = false;
         }  

         function onTouchMove(e) {
             if(isMoving) {
                 var x = e.touches[0].pageX;
                 var y = e.touches[0].pageY;
                 var dx = startX - x;
                 var dy = startY - y;
                 if(Math.abs(dx) >= min_move_x) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    cancelTouch();
                    if(dx > 0) {
                        config.wipeLeft();
                    }
                    else {
                        config.wipeRight();
                    }
                 }
                else if(Math.abs(dy) >= min_move_y) {
                        cancelTouch();
                     }
             }
         }

         function onTouchStart(e)
         {
             if (e.touches.length == 1) {
                 startX = e.touches[0].pageX;
                 startY = e.touches[0].pageY;
                 isMoving = true;
                 this.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
             }
         }       
         if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
             this.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
         }
     });

     return this;
   };

 })(jQuery);


 $("html").touchwipe({
     wipeLeft: function() { alert("left");  },
     wipeRight: function() { alert("right");  },
});
```